# Как преобразовать строку в массив int?

Tags: c++

Нужно преобразовать строку(количество элементов не известно) в массив типа int и вывести i-тый элемент массива

```
int main()
{
    string x;
    getline(cin, x);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "преобразовать"? Что содержится в строке? Почему в вопросе об этом ни слова не сказано?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::string x = "1 2 3";

std::istringstream ss(x);
std::vector<int> vec(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), {});

if (ss.fail())
    // ошибка
```

Вместо массива здесь вектор, потому что для массива нужно откуда-то знать его размер во время компиляции.

Comment: В качестве конечного итератора можно использовать фигурные скобки `{}`.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Умно, не знал.

Comment: Ну это же конструктор по умолчанию вызывает для типа аргумента.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Не, это я понимаю. Мне в голову не приходило так написать именно для этого случая.

Comment: Наверное из-за шаблонности конструктора. Но так так типы обоих параметров одинаковы - оно работает.